# re size the UITable view textlabel

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, textlabel

I created a UITableView and wrote the following code in **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RootViewControllerCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView queueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;    

}

// Set appropriate labels for the cells.
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Static Scenes";             
        **[cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 20, 500,600)];**
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"RunOptionsImage.png"];
        cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(15, 20, 55, 65);
        break;
```

as you can understand from the above code, i have a tableview cell textLabel named as **Static Scenes** .

in this code **[cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 20, 500,600)];** i am planning to set the frame of textLabel.but it not resizing according to the frame i set.
i used this cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(200, 20, 500,600) code also.
can any one tell me a good way to re size the text label.

Comment: If any of the answers helped, you should accept it. If you need any further assistance on this problem, mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to altering the text label's size you will also need to return an appropriate height in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Otherwise, any layout changes won't reflect.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you should never modify anything but cell content within a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Check out one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937319/changing-an-object-in-uitableviewcell-is-also-changing-the-object-of-a-reused-uit) from a while back. Summary:

> So the golden rule is: NEVER change
>   the cell structure after you've dequed
>   it. If you need to change the
>   structure then use DIFFERENT cell IDs.
>   Of course the more customizable is the
>   cell the easier is the possibility to
>   reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that UITableView actually lays out the cell after it asks for cellForRowAtIndexPath. While I agree with donalbain's answer in that you should use a customizable cell, I believe you can get the functionality you want by changing the frame inside this delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```